# How to get a slippy map from OziExplorer .map and .png tiles?

Tags: convert, tiles, mobile-atlas-creator

I have a bunch of topographic maps in the format of .map files and 4000x4000px png files.I would like to view them as a slippy map and be able to select an area and export that as one big image. I am wondering what my options are. QGis would be nice, or Mobile Atlas Creator, which supports local tiles as source for the following formats: OSMTracker, AndNav, BackCountry Navigator, Maverick and OSMAND.

It would be nice if at some time I could convert them to something more standard, like 256px tiles under a coordinate dir structure, or mbtiles so I could view it with tilemill or their server or map on a stick software.

So what are my options to getting these files to open in some slippy map way and being able to export specific areas as images.

I don't care what formats I have to convert to or which software/servers I have to install.

Answer (score 1):

[Global Mapper](http://www.globalmapper.com/) might be able to do that.

The [documentation](http://www.globalmapper.com/helpv13/Help_ImageRectification.html) states: "*There are also options on the File menu for loading control points and projection information from an OziExplorer .map*"

And Global Mapper can definitively export maps or part of maps as 256px tiles (or to other formats).

Comment: Global Mapper can load the .map files directly, from there use the *"File >> Export web format..."* menu to a tile system (there are about 10 choices).

Answer (score 1):

[gdal](/questions/tagged/gdal) v1.8+ can read (but not write) Ozi Explorer OZF2/OZFX3 raster datasets. Either the image file or the .map file can be passed to GDAL. To retrieve georeferencing specify the .map file.

The [`gdal2tiles` utility](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html) can go from source file to slippy map in one step (example commandline for windows):

```
gdal2tiles z:\data\one.map z:\data\two.map ... z:\data\five.map   d:\webmap
start d:\webmap\openlayers.html
```